# Parsing XFDL Contents - C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xfdl

I am tasked with ripping and stripping pertinent data from XFDL files. I am attempting to use XmlDocument's SelectSignleNode method to do so. However, it has proven unsuccessful.

Represntative XML:

```
<XFDL>
...
<page1>
<check3>true</check3>
</page1>
...
<page sid="PAGE1">
<check sid="CHECK9">
<value>true</value>
</check>
</page>
...
```

Code:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(memoryStream);//decoded and unzipped xfdl file
//Doesn't work
XmlNode checkBox = document.SelectSingleNode("//check[@sid='CHECK9']/value");
//Doesn't work
XmlNode checkBox = document.SelectSingleNode("//page[@sid='PAGE1']/check[@sid='CHECK9']");
MsgBox(checkBox.InnerXml);
```

Yields me System.NullReferenceException as an XmlNode isn't selected.

I think I'm having an xpath issue but I can't seem to understand where. The earlier xml node is easily selected using:

```
XmlNode checkBox = document.SelectSingleNode("//page1/check3");
MsgBox(checkBox.InnerText);
```

Displays just fine. And just to head it off at the pass, there isn't a definition of `<check9></check9>` in the `<page1>` tag.

Anyone have some insight?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there multiple nodes that could result from the xpath?

Comment: The first one: Yes. The second one: No.

I don't thin I'm missing a nested path, either.

Comment: Verified fully enumerated xpath is as follows: xfdl > page > check > value via opening XML in IE. What am I missing?

Comment: Good question! If you knew you would not be asking here. Is it possible that the @sid values are not really uppercase ? Your xpaths to elements seem to work and things break when you add the [@sid] qualifier

Comment: You're right about it breaking when adding the qualifiers. I can grab all instances of '<check>' using 'GetElementsByTagName' but doesn't want to cooperate with either 'SelectNodes' or 'SelectSingleNode'. I did leave out in my representative XML the namespaces in '<XFDL>' tag. To that end, I have instantiated 'XmlNamespaceManager' and added all namespaces and called 'SelectSingleNode("xpath", manager)' to no additional effect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here's the deal. XFDL defines a default namespace that requires an arbitrary mapping for xpath querying. In my case:

XML:

```
<XFDL xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/xfdl/8.0" ... >
```

Code:

```
manager.AddNamespace("a", "http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/xfdl/8.0");
//Append 'a:' to query elements
document.SelectSingleNode("//a:check[@sid='CHECK9']/a:value", manager);
```

The problem is compounded because `<check>` is buried in `<page>` which is defined in another namespace: xfdl. My xpath query becomes:

```
document.SelectSingleNode("//xfdl:page[@sid='PAGE1']/a:check[@sid='CHECK9']/a:value", manager);
```

Now this is rather XFDL specific but can be applied to other issues where there are multiple namespaces defined within an XML document.

**EDIT 1**
Source: http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/01/09/How-to-query-a-XPath-doc-that-has-a-default.aspx